# Convert from NSURL or AVAsset to PHAsset in Objective - C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl, phasset, ios8-share-extension

so i'm new making Share Extension, today im continue my project by creating Share Extension Video, but stuck after getting return data type NSURL (video Path file), in my method only accept PHAsset.

so my code like this

```
 [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:UTTypeVideo
                                    options:nil
                          completionHandler:^(NSURL *videoURL, NSError *error) {
                        NSURL *url = videoURL;
                        PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[url] options:nil];
                        PHAsset *asset = [fetchResult firstObject]; //always return nil
                        AVAsset *videoAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:videoURL];


getting stuck here-> [[ChatMessenger sharedManager] sendVideoMessageWithAsset:asset
                                                                      caption:captionString
                                                                         room:roomData
                                                                        start:^(MessageModel * _Nonnull message) {
                        NSLog(@"======START");
                    } progress:^(CGFloat progress, CGFloat total) {
                        NSLog(@"======PROGRESS %f TO %f", progress, total);
                    } success:^(MessageModel *message) {
                        NSLog(@"======SUCCESS");
                 **strong text**       [self finishSharedItemRequestReturningItems];
                    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
                        NSLog(@"======FAILED");
                    }];
```

is there any hint for doing from NSURL - video Share Extension to PHAsset ?